# Can't Verify User Account with PDO, blank page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

Why would this code for my verification of a user account produced a blank page?

I'm using this as the file to activate accounts from an email, and it comes up blank.

I'm sorry for the previous stupid post.. I pasted the wrong code, here is the file that still produces a blank page..

verify.php

```
    //Require Database Stuff
require("database.class.php");
require("user.php");

if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash']))
{
    $verify = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET active=:active WHERE active=0 AND email=:email and active=:active');
    $status = $verify->execute(array(':active' => 1));

    if( $status )
    {
        echo '<p>Your account has been activated, you can now login.</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Account already active, or account does not exist.</p>';
    }    

}else{

        echo "<p>Invalid URL.</p>";
    }

}
```

Comment: You're missing the `:email` parameter.

Comment: Your SQL UPDATE doesn't make much sense, with two different tests for active in the WHERE clause

Comment: I don't know what that means.. ehh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, added `':email'=>$_GET['email']`

```
 $verify = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET active=:active WHERE active=0 AND email=:email');
 $status = $verify->execute(array(':active' => 1, ':email'=>$_GET['email']));
```

Comment: I did this and I still got a blank page.